# for loop prints all values but only returns one value

Tags: python, python-2.7, return, return-value

So I have a function which loops through all file names within a directory, opens the yaml files and gets two of the properties which is a database name and a collection name. When I use the `print` statement instead of `return` within my function this will output all the filenames. However, when using a `return` statement, this will only return one value. I am really not sure why I get this output and have tried numerous amount of times to figure out why its doing this. My function is as follows:

```
def return_yml_file_names():
    """return file names from the yaml directory"""
    collections = os.listdir('yaml/')
    collections.remove('export_config.yaml')

    for file in collections :
        with open('yaml/' + file, 'r') as f:
            doc = yaml.load(f)
            collection_name = doc["config"]["collection"]+".json"
            return collection_name

print(return_yml_file_names())
```

Comment: Add each value to a list, and then return the list after the loop completes.

Comment: I have tried that , but it returns None when doing so @ekhumoro

Comment: That's because you didn't actually return the list.

Comment: or use `yield` in place of `return`

Answer (score 2):

So you're saying that when you replace `return collection_name` with `print(collection_name)`, the function works properly?

The reason for this is because `return` is a control flow statement. When the code hits a `return` statement, it immediately stops what it's doing and exits the function. Note that this means it doesn't continue to the next iteration of the `for` loop.

`print()` does not change the flow of the program; thus, the code hits it, executes it, and then continues onward to the next iteration of the `for` loop.

For this problem, I recommend

1. Make an empty list at the beginning of the function
2. Instead of `return`ing `collection_name`, add it to the list instead
3. After the `for` loop, return the now-full list.

The code would look like this:

```
def return_yml_file_names():
    """return file names from the yaml directory"""
    collections = os.listdir('yaml/')
    collections.remove('export_config.yaml')
    collection_name_list = []

    for file in collections :
        with open('yaml/' + file, 'r') as f:
            doc = yaml.load(f)
            collection_name = doc["config"]["collection"]+".json"
            collection_name_list.append(collection_name)
    return collection_name_list
```